# How to change Work Item Approval status on Deliver in RTC

Tags: clearcase, rtc

In our team, we try to implement Code Review using RTC.

Server is already configured to accept delivery of changes only when Work Item is approved.
The big issue with this approach is that once the WI is approved, it allows further multiple changesets being delivered without Reviewing them.

My question is: Can RTC be configured in such way that each delivery of ChangeSet changes the Approval Status of related Work Item to 'Pending'?
Or (worse case) delete whole approval from WI?

Answer (score 2):

> The big issue with this approach is that once the WI is approved, it allows further multiple changesets being delivered without Reviewing them.

One of the operation pre-conditions (the Source Control / Deliver Server one) does state:

> Note: To prevent users from linking new change sets to work items that already have approvals, **enable the `Prevent Linking to Approved Work Items` precondition**.

So once approved, no more change sets should be linked to that WI. If the approval means the code has been reviewed, the WI can be delivered (knowing the number of change sets hasn't changed).

---

[Farhan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/345138/farhan) adds in the comments:

> It can also be achieved by adding new approval cycle each time change-set submitted, So using this approach `workItem` will not be approved until all approvals gets approved.
>
> You would need to develop extension for it, code in this article can help you to programmatically create/modify approvals: see "[Creating, customizing, and deleting approval records programmatically with Rational Team Concert](https://jazz.net/library/article/1118)".

Comment: Ok, that is true. However, it works in slightly different way. This solution forces us to create new Work Item per each code change. I would rather stay with one WI per one Task and review the changesets submitted. Maybe it is possible to set approval on the changeset instead of WI?

Comment: It can also be achieved by adding new approval cycle each time change-set submitted, So using this approach workItem will not be approved until all approvals gets approved.

Comment: @Farhan Interesting. Do you have a link to a doc illustrating the creation/setup of that new approval cycle?

Comment: you would need to develop extension for it, code in this article can help you to programmatically create/modify approvals:
https://jazz.net/library/article/1118

Comment: @Farhan OK. I understand now why I didn't see that solution implemented before ;) It does not look trivial.

Comment: @Farhan I have included your comment and link in the answer for more visibility. Thank you for this feedback.